# Can't bind chart-data from component to view. Angular 6, predix-ui

Tags: polymer, angular6, predix

pls help. SOS

I'm trying to bind chart-data to plot graph, like:

```
[attr.chart-data]='chartData'
```

My Component:

```
export class AppComponent {
arr: Array<Object> = [];
seriesConfig: {};

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.arr = [
        { x: 1530426560000, y: 179.46 },
        { x: 1530426570000, y: 179.58 },
        { x: 1530426580000, y: 179.58 },
        { x: 1530426590000, y: 179.6 },
        { x: 1530426600000, y: 179.52 },
        { x: 1530426610000, y: 179.56 },
        { x: 1530426620000, y: 179.52 },
        { x: 1530426630000, y: 179.52 }
    ];

    this.seriesConfig = {
        y: { type: "line", name: "series1", x: "x", y: "y" }
    };
} }
```

My View:

```
<div>
<h2 id="title-tag">Timeseries</h2>
<px-vis-timeseries id="ts1" prevent-resize width="950" height="500" register-location="side" enable-tooltip="true" tooltip
 include-all-series selection-type="x" [attr.chart-data]='arr' [attr.series-config]='seriesConfig' x-axis-config='{"title": "Date"}'
 y-axis-config='{"title": "y1"}'>
</px-vis-timeseries>
```

Questions:

1. Could you please tell, how to correctly bind data?
2. What for series-config needed? How to correctly make it up?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to pass the chart data with a camelCase key, rather than dashes.  (This is the way Polymer works.)  Something like this:

```
<px-vis-timeseries [chartData]='arr'></px-vis-timeseries>
```

Some more info & links here:
https://www.predix-ui.com/#/develop/frameworks-angular

Comment: Yes, I've tried it, but in this way it doesn't work too. No warnings, no errors, only empty graph appears without any lines. Any suggestions, why so?